# Cast directly in foreach loop

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, casting

In a certain situation I have an `std::vector` of pointers to `ClassA`. Another class, `ClassB`, inherits from `ClassA`. At some point I know this vector `only` contains pointers to instances of ClassB. I iterate over the vector with a `foreach loop`, after which I `cast` the object to ClassB.

Currently this looks similar to this:

```
Class ClassA
{
}

Class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    void DoSomething();
}

std::vector<ClassA*> vecA;

void iterate()
{
    for(ClassA* obj : vecA)
    {
        ((ClassB*)obj)->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I wonder if I can directly cast the object in the foreach loop. This would be shorter, and would not require me to cast the object every time I want to use it. I am looking for something that looks like this:

```
void iterate()
{
    for((ClassB*)ClassA* obj : vecA)
    {
        obj->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this possible? And if it is not, what would be an easy way to 'save' the cast, if I want to use the casted object more than one time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(ClassB *)` is a bad idea, use `dynamic_cast<ClassB *>(...)` instead... I know it does not answer your question, but it is style thing... :(

Comment: @jsantander If he knows that the cast cannot possibly fail, a `static_cast` will be faster.

Comment: @jsantander Also, not answering a question is perfectly fine in comments ;)

Comment: if you know the vector will only hold `ClassB*`, then why not formalize that and have a `std::vector<ClassB*>` ?

Comment: @FredOverflow The design is indeed pretty bad at the moment, and everything is being rewritten at the moment. However, I was wondering if it was possible. At the moment creating a vector of ClassB pointers is not yet possible.

Comment: _At the moment_ what is allowed then!?

Comment: I described in my question what is the current situation. FredOverflow explained this syntax is not possible, and the answer of Yakk explained the best alternative, and I will accept this answer.

Comment: Hmm, what about an intermediate class utilizing `boost::transform_iterator`? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html

Comment: Thanks you for the idea, but I prefer not to use non c++ standard libraries.

Comment: Shouldn't DoSomething be a virtual function in ClassA?

Comment: @dalle It seems I reinvented `boost::transform_iterator`, just a lot less generic :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void iterate() {
  for(ClassA* obj_ : vecA) {
    Assert(dynamic_cast<ClassB*>(obj_)); // debug build sanity check
    auto* obj = static_cast<ClassB*>(obj_);
    obj->DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: That is indeed what I have at the moment. Will the performance be any different from directly casting? I wonder, because of the extra variable. I expect the compiler to optimize this.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as "efficient dereferencing". When optimizing code, it becomes invaluable when you have nested structs and you need to routinely access lowest-level members in a loop, as this type of approach saves you multiple casting operations per loop iteration.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I will accept this answer as it gave me the best alternative to what I originally wanted.

Comment: You don't need additional variables for casting: `static_cast<ClassB*>(obj_)->DoSomething();`

Comment: @fredoverflow yes, but OP wanted repeated use.  And it makes each line simpler.

Answer (score 2):

How about a container wrapper? Let's look at the usage first:

```
void iterate()
{
    for (ClassB* obj : cast_range<ClassB*>(vecA))
    {
        obj->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And here is one possible implementation:

```
template<typename Target, typename Underlying>
struct cast_iterator_t
{
    Underlying it;

    Target operator*() const
    {
        return (Target) *it;
    }

    bool operator==(cast_iterator_t that) const
    {
        return it == that.it;
    }   

    bool operator!=(cast_iterator_t that) const
    {
        return it != that.it;
    }   

    cast_iterator_t& operator++()
    {
        ++it;
        return *this;
    }

    cast_iterator_t operator++(int)
    {
        cast_iterator_t old(*this);
        ++*this;
        return old;
    }
};

template<typename Target, typename Underlying>
cast_iterator_t<Target, Underlying> cast_iterator(Underlying it)
{
    return {it};
}

template<typename Target, typename Range>
struct cast_range_t
{
    Range& range;

    decltype(cast_iterator<Target>(std::begin(range))) begin()
    {
      return cast_iterator<Target>(std::begin(range));
    }

    decltype(cast_iterator<Target>(std::end(range))) end()
    {
      return cast_iterator<Target>(std::end(range));
    }
};

template<typename Target, typename Range>
cast_range_t<Target, Range> cast_range(Range& range)
{
    return {range};
}
```

Comment: While I like the fact you tried answered my favourite option, I am not going to use this, as I cannot confirm this is actually correct. It abuses the fact that you know how the std::vector works, and I am not sure if it is specified that a std::vector always uses memory in the same way using different compilers.

Comment: @Yakk I replaced the `reinterpret_cast` hack with template wankery ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow Now, tonnes of template wankery for little to no performance increase (but no performance cost), but it looks prettier at the point of use!  +1 -- I am always a fan of `template` wankery (as an aside, your `cast_iterator_t` lacks an iterator category, which may be a good thing as it doesn't return a reference from `*`, and that breaks stuff) (as a second aside, you should perfect forward the `Range&&`, and store a `Range` (no `&&`), which gives you proper temporary lifetime extension, important when you daisy-chain more than one such range mutator)

Comment: It would be nice to [support rvalue ranges, check with `dynamic_cast` when possible, and properly tag the iterator category](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6e51371dda7a700).

Comment: @Casey almost perfect!  Closer to perfect would support as many iterator operations on the base type as possible (including possibly assignment?), decaying the iterator type as little as possible, and specializing `std::make_move_iterator`.